# Ideal generated by maximal ideal and some other element of integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be an integral domain, $M$ a maximal ideal of $R[x]$ and $M \cap R=(0)$. Let $0\neq p\in R$. Then prove that $(M,p)=R[x]$.

Comment: Since $p\notin M$, $(M,p)$ is an ideal that is larger than $M$. Now use that $M$ is maximal.

Comment: It seems that the OP has made a strange edit to their own question. I tried to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Since $0 \neq p \in R$ and $M \cap R = (0)$, it follows that $p$  is not in $M$. Thus, the ideal $(p, M)$ is strictly larger than $M$. By maximality of $M$, it follows that $(p, M) = R[x]$.